# How to get the logged-in user's ID in Symfony

Tags: symfony, dql

I am developing an application using Symfony and Doctrine ORM. I would like to know how to get the currently logged-in user's ID.

Comment: In symfony2.1 controllers, you can get user by calling $this->getUser(). I think it is new in this version of symfony.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

**Current Symfony versions (Symfony 4, Symfony >=3.2)**

[Since **Symfony >=3.2**](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-user-value-resolver-for-controllers) you can simply expect a `UserInterface` implementation to be injected to your controller action directly. You can then call `getId()` to retrieve user's identifier:

```php
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    // when the user is mandatory (e.g. behind a firewall)
    public function fooAction(UserInterface $user)
    {
        $userId = $user->getId(); 
    }

    // when the user is optional (e.g. can be anonymous)
    public function barAction(UserInterface $user = null) 
    {
        $userId = null !== $user ? $user->getId() : null;
    }
}
```

You can still use the security token storage as in all Symfony versions since 2.6. For example, in your controller:

```
$user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
```

Note that *the `Controller::getUser()` shortcut mentioned in the next part of this answer is no longer encouraged.*

**Legacy Symfony versions**

The easiest way to access the user used to be to extend the base controller, and use the shortcut `getUser()` method:

```
$user = $this->getUser();
```

Since **Symfony 2.6** you can retrieve a user from the security token storage:

```
$user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
```

**Before Symfony 2.6**, the token was accessible from the security context service instead:

```
$user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
```

Note that *the security context service is deprecated in Symfony 2 and was removed in Symfony 3.0.*

Comment: Nice answer. To **get other fields from user object** like email, firstname or gender. Use like this. To get gender, **echo 'Gender is : ' . $user->getGender();**

Comment: Deprecated since version 2.6, to be removed in 3.0. !

Comment: getUser() is still used in Symfony 4+ per the docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-fetching-the-user-object

Comment: @Zagloo, I just used the "UserInterface" inside the controller in my Symfony 5, and it worked just as expected.

Comment: Hi Jakub, is there any chance you could update this a bit to confirm whether this is still the way to do it in the later versions of Symfony (at least 5, but ideally up to 7)? This Q&A is close to being a suitable canonical target for all other questions, but it's currently a bit too focused on Symfony 2-4 only.

Answer (score 17):

In symfony2, we can get this simpler by this code:

```
$id = $this->getUser()->getId();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get the variable with the code below:

```
$userId = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getId();
```

Answer (score 0):

This can get dressed in the method:

```
/**
 * Get user id
 * @return integer $userId
 */
protected function getUserId()
{
    $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    $userId = $user->getId();

    return $userId;
}
```

And induction $this->getUserId()

```
public function example()
{
    print_r($this->getUserId()); 
}
```